# Is there a way to disable passwords for free apps on iPhone 4?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, iphone, password

Under `Settings > iTunes & App Store` there is no `Password Settings` option for me on my newly activated iPhone 4. From reading [this article](http://www.iphoneincanada.ca/how-to/fix-ios-8-3-missing-password-settings-2/), it seems this might be a bug and that I have to turn off Touch ID to access this setting. But iPhone 4 has no touch id. The hardware isn't there, nor is the software.

How can I turn off password prompting for free apps? Is there any way?

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your `iTunes & App Store -> Password Settings` screen?  It seems very strange that you don't have that option.

Comment: As requested. Kind of a huge screenshot but oh well.

Comment: What do you see when you go to 'Settings -> Passcode'?